# How to create a PDF document from scratch in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf

How can I create a PDF document from scratch in Python?

I want to

- place text in an easy way (without having to specify exact coordinates)
- use fonts, colors, italic, bold
- use tables
- use lists
- use images

Comment: **Recommendation** questions are **off-topic** on Stack Overflow. There is [softwarerecs.se], but note on their rules about the questions. You could transform the question for ask about **specific library**, so it will both be on-topic and retain the answer in the same (or very similar) form.

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: I am the author of the library being used in this answer.

Using `pText` you can achieve this easily.

Let's start by creating an empty `Document`

```
# create document
pdf = Document()
```

We can then add an empty `Page` to the `Document`

```
# add page
page = Page()
pdf.append_page(page)
```

Now we need to select a `PageLayout`. This class will act like a layout manager. It will keep track of where the available space is, and will lay out components in that space (taking into account margins, leading, etc)

Here I'm using a `MultiColumnLayout` with 2 columns:

```
layout = MultiColumnLayout(page, number_of_columns=2)
```

Now I'm going to add 2 `Paragraph` objects, one for the title, and one for the author:

```
layout.add(Paragraph("The Raven", font_size=Decimal(20)))
layout.add(Paragraph("Edgar Allen Poe", font="Helvetica-Oblique", font_size=Decimal(8), font_color=X11Color("SteelBlue")))
```

Notice that I specified the font, font_size, and font_color.
I could also specify a justification (left, right, full, center). But I'll leave that as is for now.

Finally, we'll add a few repeats of the first verse of "The Raven"

```
for _ in range(0, 10):
    layout.add(Paragraph(
        "Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered, weak and weary, Over many a quaint and curious volume of forgotten lore- While I nodded, nearly napping, suddenly there came a tapping, As of some one gently rapping, rapping at my chamber door. Tis some visitor, I muttered, tapping at my chamber door- Only this and nothing more.",
        font_size=Decimal(12),
        font_color=X11Color("SlateGray"),
        justification=Justification.FLUSH_LEFT,
    ))
```

And now all that's left is to store the `Document`

```
# attempt to store PDF
with open("output.pdf", "wb") as in_file_handle:
    PDF.dumps(in_file_handle, pdf)
```

The result should be something like this:

[image]

Check out the other examples to get an idea of how to use tables and lists:

- [Tables](https://github.com/jorisschellekens/ptext-release/blob/master/EXAMPLES.md#46-adding-a-simple-table)
- [Lists](https://github.com/jorisschellekens/ptext-release/blob/master/EXAMPLES.md#48-adding-an-ordered-list)
- much more

Comment: Are you the author of pText, or in any way affiliated with it? If so, please disclose prominently.

Comment: Done. Thanks. I'd completely forgotten about that.

Comment: Do you think you could refrain from posting off topic questions in a blatant effort to advertise your software?

Comment: I've been a member of SO for a while now. I fail to see which rule I am breaking by answering my own question (about a piece of software I wrote). I think the very intent of being allowed to answer your own question is to provide some kind of documentation for certain scenarios or situations. So, kindly point me towards the exact rule you think I am breaking, and I shall of course refrain from breaking it.

Comment: Your answers are actually pretty thorough and well written. Your question definitely fall under the "unclear what you're asking" or "asking for documentation or software" close reasons. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Perhaps if you focused on solving concrete use-cases rather than advertisement? Showing an example where another library fails at something would even be appropriate. I'm assuming you wrote this library for a specific reason.

Comment: I would not want to shame another pdf library creator. I wrote it because I like well-documented, object oriented, well-tested code. And I found the current offer in python to be lacking. I used to work at another pdf company (java based), so I was fortunately in a position where I could write my own alternative.

Comment: I am not suggesting you deliberately shame another library. However, if you have a use-case that another library can not fulfill, that becomes a matter of fact. My objection is not to your library, your answers, or even your attempts at advertising it more widely. My objection is to the crappy questions you are writing to do it. Based on my prior experience with some automated PDF tasks, there are dozens of existing questions you can add answers to without having to artificially contrive your own.